# Stop iPhone from reducing video quality <input type=“file”>

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I am building a small web app that lets a user upload a video to a server. I use  for the user to select their file. They get these upload options:
[image]

If they choose to take a video in safari, the quality is greatly reduced to 360p. If they select a video that was taken beforehand, the quality is reduced to 720p (either that or 1080p, I forget.)

Here is a link describing this process: https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.addpipe.com/video-quality-when-recording-videos-from-safari-on-ios-through-html-media-capture/amp/

I want to know if it is possible to disable this compression - I want them to have the ability to upload videos in their actual size, uncompressed. I have tried searching google with no avail.

Comment: Is this behavior replicable on both cellular and WiFi?

Comment: Yes, both on WiFi and Cellular. Happens in both chrome and safari on iOS

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I found for this is to use the `multiple` attribute.
It's a bit inconvenient to let the user pick multiple files but by doing it this way, it doesn't compress the file.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work for HEVC file tho